# Distance between two coordinates in 3D space of a prism

Tags: c, 3d, coordinates, distance

I have a homework problem that asks the user for the vertices of a rectangular prism located in 3-D space. I need to calculate the surface area and volume of the prism. I have to have a function that calculates the distance between two points on the prism, i am able to ask the get the information from the user of what the coordinates are

```
double cx1, cy1, cz1, cx2, cy2, cz2, cx3, cy3, cz3, cx4, cy4, cz4, cx5, cy5, cz5, cx6, cy6, cz6, cx7, cy7, cz7, cx8, cy8, cz8;

int main() {
    printf("Enter the first coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx1, &cy1, &cz1);
    printf("Enter the second coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx2, &cy2, &cz2);
    printf("Enter the third coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx3, &cy3, &cz3);
    printf("Enter the fourth coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx4, &cy4, &cz4 );
    printf("Enter the fifth coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx5, & cy5, &cz5);
    printf("Enter the sixth coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx6, &cy6, &cz6);
    printf("Enter the seventh coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &cx7, &cy7, &cz7);
    printf("Enter the eighth coordinate in the form x y z: \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&cx8, &cy8, &cz8);


return get_dist(cx1, cx2, cy1, cy2);
```

}

i then assigned each x y and z coordinate to a variable this is all in the main function...then i did this for one point:

```
double get_dist(cx1,cx2,cy1, cy2){
    double distance1_2;
    distance1_2 = sqrt(((cx2 - cx1)*(cx2 - cx1)) - ((cy2 - cy1)*(cy2 - cy1)) );

    printf("%lf",distance1_2);

return 0;
}
```

and it gave me the correct value 2 but is there an easier/faster way of doing this than having to do each coordinate individually?

Comment: Your distance calculation is wrong by the way.

Comment: group 3 coordinates in a `Point3` (or smthg) structure. Make an array of the 8 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you could to to decrease your headache with so many variables:

- Create a structure to group all 3 coordinates of a point
- create and array for your points

Like this:

```
struct Point3 {
  double x, y, z;
}; // <-- the semocolon (;) is mandatory here

// hack so that you can use `Point3` instead of `struct Point3` when 
// referring to the structure type. This is completely unnecessary in C++
typedef struct Point3 Point3; 

int const g_num_points = 8; // this is actually an instance where
                            // a global variable is arguably not that bad

int main() {
  Point3 points[g_num_points]; // avoid global variables like plague
  int i;
  int ret;

  for (i = 0; i < g_num_points; ++i) {
    printf("Enter the %d'th coordinate in the form x y z: \n", i);
    ret = scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &(points[i].x), &(points[i].y), &(points[i].z));
    if (ret != 3) {
       // deal with invalid input. Since this is homework
       // I will leave it as an exercise for you
    }
  }
}
```

Since this is homework I will leave you to figure it out how to write the `get_distance` function using the `Point3` structure.

And btw, the distance between two points in 3d coordinates involves... well... two points and with each point having 3 coordinates, you have 6 coordinates. Your function takes only 4 coordinates as input parameters. Using a structure like this to represent a point by it's 3 coordinates should make it more obvious how to fix that.

Comment: how does all this sound to you?

Comment: I'm using c not c++ , the above code i shrunk it to test try the code, while i kept working on it i realized that i needed to involve the z so i added it in like the x and y above  so instead i replaced them with something like this distance1_2 = sqrt(((cx2 - cx1)*(cx2 - cx1)) - ((cy2 - cy1)*(cy2 - cy1) - (cz2 - cz1)*(cz2 - cz1)) ); although i guess my original question want worded correctly i wanted to know if there was a faster way to get the distance without doing each one individually although individually still gives me the correct answer as well